# How to have a 'mouse hovering' feature on a PHP table (values fetched from a MySQL table) of a webpage

Tags: javascript, php, css, mysql

I have three MySQL tables: TBL1, TBL2 and TBL3

```
TBL1:
id     type      name
1      Geo1     GeoTest1
2      Geo2     GeoTest2

TBL2:
id    attributes  status
1      river1       P
1      river2       F
1      river3       F
2      river1       F
2      river3       P

TBL3:
attributes    attr_area  status    id
river1       river1_ar0    P        1
river1       river1_ar1    P        1
river1       river1_ar2    P        1
river2       river2_ar0    F        1
river2       river2_ar1    F        1
river1       river1_ar0    P        2
river1       river1_ar1    P        2
river1       river1_ar2    F        2
river3       river3_ar0    P        2
river3       river3_ar0    F        1
```

I have already created a PHP webpage which displays the table in the following manner:

```
Type   river1  river2  river3
Geo1     P       F       F
Geo2     F               P
```

Now I want to create a hovering feature on the status. Let's say when I hover my mouse on 'F' for Type = 'Geo2' and river1 it should have a pop up showing this (data fetched from TBL3):

```
Failed attr_area:
river1_ar2
```

Similarly, when I hover over "F" (Geo1 and river2) the pop up should display:

```
Failed attr_area:
river2_ar0
river2_ar1
```

How can I achieve this on a PHP webpage? Is it possible through only PHP or do I have to use some other web technologies with PHP?

The SQL query for popup :

```
select attr_area from TBL3 where status = 'F' and attributes = 'river1' and id in (select id from TBL1 where type = 'Geo2')
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can do it through CSS or JS. Both the CSS or JS required for the hover effect can be written in PHP

Comment: Hovering works in the Browser, so you need JavaScript or CSS/Stylesheet. Example of a simple selector in css table:hover tr { background: red; } which makes all trs having a red backround, when hovering the table.